# Is it possible to add datepicker in ionic 4 alerts

Tags: ionic-framework, datepicker

I want to add a datepicker inside a popup.Currently we have a alert box with to checkbox. As a new feature I want to add a datepicker below the checkbox.

Answer (score 3):

You can try with this solution,

```
const alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
      inputs: [
        // input date with min & max
        {
          name: 'name4',
          type: 'date',
          min: '2017-03-01',
          max: '2018-01-12'
        },
        // input date without min nor max
        {
          name: 'name5',
          type: 'date'
        },
      ],
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          cssClass: 'secondary',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Confirm Cancel');
          }
        }, {
          text: 'Ok',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Confirm Ok');
          }
        }
      ]
    });

    return await alert.present();
```

[image]

For more Info : 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/alert

Otherwise you could easily create a modal component and reduce its size to be closer to that of the alert dialog box.

Comment: Thank you so much for ur response.I created a model and reduced its size.And it works.